# Is it possible to expose a top-level function from a Gradle settings plugin written in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

I have a working Gradle Settings plugin written in Groovy that makes a top-level function available to consumer `settings.gradle`s when applied. For consistency with other projects, I'd like to convert it to Kotlin, but I can't find a way to do it.

#### In a Groovy plugin (works)

```java
package com.example.sayhello

import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Settings> {
    @Override
    void apply(Settings settings) {
        settings.ext.sayHello = { name -> println("Hello, $name") }
    }
}
```

```
// settings.gradle
plugins {
    com.example.sayhello
}

sayHello("Rob")
```

#### In a Kotlin plugin

`settings.ext` does not compile

```kotlin
class MyPlugin : Plugin<Settings> {
    override fun apply(settings: Settings) {
        settings.ext.sayHello = fun(name: String) {
            println("Hello, $name")
        }
    }
}
```

*fails to compile, with*

```
Unresolved reference: ext
```

`settings.extensions.extraProperties`, which seems to be the closest equivalent, doesn't seem to be exposed as a top level function:

```kotlin
class MyPlugin : Plugin<Settings> {
    override fun apply(settings: Settings) {
        settings.extensions.extraProperties["sayHello"] = fun(name: String) {
            println("Hello, $name")
        }
    }
}
```

*leads to, when building a consumer `settings.gradle`*

```
Could not find method sayHello() for arguments [Rob] on settings 'android' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings
```

**Is there any way to convert this Groovy plugin to Kotlin without changing the public API? If not, what constraint of Kotlin prevents something Groovy/Java allows?**

Comment: Apart from that, I'm wondering why you need to register a plugin for this. Can't you just put the function in `buildSrc` and call it directly from your buildscript?

Comment: @Jorn re `buildSrc` - for context, this public plugin is part of an app framework, and I'm keen to minimise code in framework user space. I want to be able to say to our users "add these two lines to your `settings.gradle`", rather than "create this file and paste these functions in". I'd also rather encapsulate the implementation so we can release patches as new plugin versions, rather than asking users to change code in their projects.

Comment: I see. Well, the one thing I'm fairly sure about is you can't just call functions from a map like that in Kotlin. At the very least, you'd have to cast to something you can call `invoke` on.

Comment: I'm getting that impression. If that's the answer I'm curious why though - naively, isn't it all just Java in the end? :) The consumer code (`settings.gradle`) is Groovy in both cases.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Groovy, but there might be some trickery in the Groovy compiler itself that allows such a feature. And that won't be the case for Kotlin.

Comment: Groovy can do all sorts of not-typesafe-or-compiler-checked things. You can use any arbitrary text as if it were a variable and it will pull the value from your Gradle properties file. It must be using a lot of reflection under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides that usages of `ext` / `extra` / `extraProperties` are practically always a work-around for not doing something properly, the `extraProperties` you found are indeed what the Groovy DSL `ext` sugar also uses under the hood.

Your problem is, that in your Kotlin version you set the value as a Kotlin function, and your Groovy consumer does not know how to call that. It needs something with a `call` method iirc. If you set the value for example to a closure (e.g. a `KotlinClosure1<String, Any>` instance), it should work like before.

Comment: Appreciate the insight but using a closure `settings.extensions.extraProperties["sayHello"] = { name: String -> println("Hello, $name") }` still gives me the same result on the consumer end: `Could not find method sayHello() for arguments...`.

Comment: I'd gladly take input on the way to do this "properly" btw - our React Native users need to `includeBuild` another Gradle plugin located within `node_modules` installed via a JavaScript package manager, and this settings plugin implements the Node JS resolution algorithm to find the correct path to that other plugin. I'm a JS infra guy trying to solve a problem with no idea about Gradle :|

Comment: What you showed in your comment is not a Groovy closure, it is a Kotlin lambda expression. Same problem as with the anonymous function you used in your original post.

Comment: I cannot tell you how you create a Groovy Closure object from Kotlin code, Google it, you are for sure not the first one needing that. And besides that, as I mentioned, you probably don't need to, but having anything with a `call` method that takes a `String` argument should be fine for Groovy iirc, as said in my answer.

Comment: Ah, I missed the distinction between "closure" and "Groovy Closure object". Indeed, the snippet below works as I wanted (and might help others to add to your answer). Thanks.

`settings.extensions.extraProperties["sayHello"] = object : groovy.lang.Closure<Unit>(this) { fun doCall(name: String): Unit { println("Hello, $name") } }`

Answer (score 2):

From the [Gradle documentation here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#groovy_closures_from_kotlin):

> You may sometimes have to call Groovy methods that take Closure
> arguments from Kotlin code. For example, some third-party plugins
> written in Groovy expect closure arguments. In order to provide a way
> to construct closures while preserving Kotlin’s strong typing, two
> helper methods exist:
>
> - `closureOf<T> {}`
> - `delegateClosureOf<T> {}`
>
> Both methods are useful in different circumstances and depend upon the
> method you are passing the Closure instance into.

But then it says:

> These two utility functions are useful for configuration closures, but
> some plugins might expect Groovy closures for other purposes. The
> `KotlinClosure0` to `KotlinClosure2` types allows adapting Kotlin
> functions to Groovy closures with more flexibility.

You have a single parameter. A Closure must always have a return type. So I think you need a `KotlinClosure1<String, Any>`. (I didn't test this myself.)

```
class MyPlugin : Plugin<Settings> {
    override fun apply(settings: Settings) {
        settings.extra["sayHello"] = KotlinClosure1<String, Any>({ name ->
            println("Hello, $name")
        })
    }
}
```